# How do you show the active page/tab with css/javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation

I want to do something very similar to this website: http://feed-the-beast.com/

Where when you click on navigation link, the page will slide down to the appropriate id, and the "active" navigation button is highlighted in some way. How can i do this? I also want to do this for more than one page, since I will also have a separate page for a forum.

EDIT: How can I also accomplish the sliding down the page?

Comment: Right click on the page and view source. It seems to be an plain Javascript and HTML. Nothing magical about it

Comment: look at the source, its done with javascript

Comment: I realize its plain JS lol I am just not familiar with JS at all, but with a little explanation I could pick it up fairly easily. I just want to be able to edit it myself, not just copy/paste off of that website (also copyright)

Answer (score 2):

See the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/4sGmG/1/

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <a href="#one">One</a>
    <a href="#two">Two</a>
    <a href="#three">Three</a>
    <a href="#four">Four</a>
    <a href="#five">Five</a>
</nav>

<div id="one">One</div>
<div id="two">Two</div>
<div id="three">Three</div>
<div id="four">Four</div>
<div id="five">Five</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('nav a').on('click', function() {
    var activeDiv = $(this).attr('href');

    //setActiveMenuItem($(this));

    $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: $(activeDiv).offset().top
    }, 2000);        
});

$(window).on('scroll', function(e) {
    var bodyTop = $(document).scrollTop();

    $('div').each(function() {
        var offset = $(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();

        if (offset >= 0) {
            setActiveMenuItem($(this).attr('id'));

            return false;
        }
    });
});

function setActiveMenuItem(id) {
    $('a[href=#' + id + ']').addClass('active');
    $('a[href=#' + id + ']').siblings().removeClass('active');
}
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with JS. What do the siblings() and animate() functions do? Also does this cover just manually scrolling down the page like it does on the website in the OP?

Comment: `siblings()` select all elements on the same level as the selected element. `animate()` animates a change of styles, in this case it scrolls down the page. And no, it doesn't cover manually scrolling, but you can do that with jQuery / JavaScript as well.

Comment: @Xzar I've updated my answer and added a working demo. Could you please accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Basic anchor navigation, softened with JavaScript (jQuery), will do the trick. Get familiar with Firebug or Chrome's developer tools to see how that site is done.

Twitter Bootstrap offers ScrollSpy, a position detection mechanism that may also be useful. http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#scrollspy

Comment: Great, thanks. I'll have a look through this.